# Total amount of passwords

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's suppose I want to create a password *exactly 8 characters* long, derived from a pool of 95 characters. Is the total amount of passwords I could possibly make simply $95^8$ (6,​634,​204,​312,​890,​625)?

Secondly, suppose my password *can be upto 8 characters long*, derived from a pool of 95 characters. Is the total amount of passwords I can create computed the same way, or would it be something like... $95^0$ + $95^1$ + $95^2$ + $95^3$ + $95^4$ + $95^5$ + $95^6$ + $95^7$ + $95^8$ (6,704,780,954,517,120)?

Lastly, is the correct term for these called *permutations*, or...?

Thanks for the assist!

Comment: Yes, both of your answers seem correct. However, you may want to exclude the trivial 0-character password.

Comment: This is correct because you are adding up all the permutations for passwords of length 0, 1, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. for every character you have 95 option, thus making $95 \times 95 \times... = 95^8$.
For the second one - yes as well.

And no, it isn't called permutations, since permutations are ways to organize $n$ values in a raw of length $n$, for example, the num of permutations for this will be $n!$.

Comment: So to be clear then... BOTH of my scenarios are reflecting the proper math in each one?

Comment: @mac  Yes they are :)

Comment: assuming you allow 'no password' at all (this is the $95^0$ option - password of length 0)

Comment: I appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: It's my understanding the first scenario involves permutations. What would I call the second scenario?

Comment: permutations are usually when distinct objects are rearranged in a row. In this case, both of the scenarios does not include distinct objects, since for example the password 11111111 is legal. For example, if asked how many permutations are to arrange 1's in a row of eight - there is only one permutation since they are all the same objects.

Comment: As far for the name of the scenarios - the first one be **the rule of product**, and the second scenario is both **the rule of product** and **the rule of sum**.